# CredentialsCache.DefaultCredentials within Task / Thread

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, task-parallel-library, credentialscache

I hope you can help me.

I am doing some webrequests within my C# 4.0 application which require authentication. I simply use the `CredentialsCache.DefaultCredentials`. This works great as long as I do not run the  functionality in a different thread / task via `Task<T>.Factory.StartNew(...)`. I then get 401 errors. I assume that the credentials are not passed through to child threads?

How can I pass through the credentials to any child tasks / threads?

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution for this?

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you are using impersonation and that the problem *is* that the credentials are not being flowed into the Task. It's worth checking this point to save a wild goose chase by dumping out the value of `Windows.Identity.GetCurrent().Name` in both the initiating code and the Task body and making sure it's what you expect.

So given the above, there are a couple of ways that (to put it formally) execution context (or just security context) is not being flowed across threads. The default behaviour is that context *is* flowed - so something must be affecting that.

1) Something has set `ExecutionContext.SuppressFlow()` - you can check this by dumping the value of `ExecutionContext.IsFlowSuppressed()` inside the task.

2) There is a configuration element `<legacyImpersonationPolicy>` (conifguration->runtime->legacyImpersonationPolicy) that defaults to `false`. When `false`, WindowsIdentity *is* flowed across asychronous points. When `true` it *is not*. This is regardless of the ExecutionContext flow settings. So `true` here would cause a problem for you. You can check this by dumping the value of `SecurityContext.IsWindowsIdentityFlowSuppressed()` is your task. This can also be programmatically set per thread with `SecurityContext.SuppressFlowWindowsIdentity()`.

Finally, for completeness, in case you are using unmanaged code there is another setting `<alwaysFlowImpersonationPolicy>` that controls how impersonated credentials are flowed in unmanaged scenarios as well; the other settings described only affect managed code.

Comment: My interpretation of `I am doing some webrequests within my C# 4.0 application which require authentication` is that he is calling web services using `HttpWebRequest`

Comment: Yes, you're quite right; just realised that myself and edited the question to reflect.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'll test it soon although I doubt that I changed the default behaviour of those settings. And yes, I am using impersonation.

Comment: My test results yield that SecurityContext.IsWindowsIdentityFlowSuppressed is True. Although I never touched the machine.config or changed the legacyImpersonationPolicy. Then, I added to my web.config the legacyImpersonationPolicy enabled set to false. Didn't help. Then I looked in the Microsoft.NET directory and changed the same setting in Aspnet.config (Which was actually set to true! Why?). But still, didn't help.

Comment: Is there a way to centralize these setting to the specific area in code where a call HttpWebRequest is made? I don't specifically understand the side effects of changing these settings which will produce a machine wide change. Especially security risks.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else comes across this issue... mine was a little different. My WCF service is exposed as a REST service as well as a SOAP, with the security context coming from either System.Web.HttpContext.Current or System.ServiceModel.OperationContext.Current. My DAL uses one of those contexts to identify the current user by checking HttpContext.Current.User.Identity or OperationContext.Current.ClaimsPrincipal.Identity.

So for my case, I had to save those two contexts in variables outside of the parallel foreach and then set them inside the parallel to the saved values. That seemed to do the trick. The same concept could work for other TPL situations with some modifications.

```
var httpcontext = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
var opcontext = System.ServiceModel.OperationContext.Current;
Parallel.ForEach(types, (p) =>
{
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current = httpcontext;
    System.ServiceModel.OperationContext.Current = opcontext;

    // DO YOUR PARALLEL PROCESSING HERE
});
```